# Electronic signature on a pdf file HTML5

Tags: html, web-applications, tablet, signature

I've been given a task where I must generate a PDF file, then the customer performs an electronic signature in a certain area on the document.

It will be used on a tablet (I don't know much about it). It must be also be a part of web application, and I've been told that HTML5 can handle this nicely.

Could anyone give me a tip how to start working on this? I have hardly any experience with HTML5.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the "very" late reply but I got the same work recently

I am using sencha 2 touch, in which am using a PDF viewer in js Itself try this

https://github.com/SunboX/st2_pdf_panel

For the signature part try using this

https://github.com/SimFla/SimFla-signaturePad

mind you signature pad needed a lot of changes.

else another solution would be using Mozilla's pdf.js, display that on the canvas and use the same canvas to draw on the signature.

Thanks. Do share if you have already solved this.

Comment: The signature-pad link you had specified above is not working. Somebody landing here in search of a solution to sign PDF from Web Browser may refer to my answere https://stackoverflow.com/a/55676351/9659885

Answer (score 0):

There are also commercial solutions, with an API that allows integration into your environments. Check out Namirial.com (former xyzmo), on www.xyzmo.com or www.significant.com